# String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am updating my database using the `update-database` command in Entity Framework and it is raising an error with the message: `String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated`

How can I allow the update to work?

Comment: You'll need to add the source code for the properties on your class on this - at a guess, you've not annotated the property correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DbUpdateException: Which field is causing "String or binary data would be truncated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396895/dbupdateexception-which-field-is-causing-string-or-binary-data-would-be-trunca)

Comment: Check out this answer if you want to catch the offending fields using C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71341426/8644294

Answer (score 18):

Take this code first entity:

```
public class Something
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

That will create a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which will let you pretty much store any size text.

Now we apply an annotation like this:

```
public class Something
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So now the migration from this has to **shorten** your column to 50 characters only. If you have entries that are longer that 50 characters, you will get that error message.

**Solution 1**

Fix the data! Remove any data longer than 50 characters. Using SQL, either delete the offending rows:

```sql
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE LEN(MyColumn) > 50
```

Or, probably a better idea is to manually truncate the data:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = LEFT(MyColumn, 50)
WHERE LEN(MyColumn) > 50
```

**Solution 2** (not 100% sure this will work)

Let the migration truncate the data by using this command:

```
Update-Database -Force
```

Comment: Using the `-Force` flag doesn't override the truncation error.


However, running the `UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = LEFT(MyColumn, 50)` did allow the `Update-Database` command to complete successfully.

Comment: VS2019. -Force doesn't work. I had a column NVARCHAR(60) and wanted to set it to NVARCHAR(6) with a code-first migration. There was just one existing row in the table with 10 characters in the column, while all the rest were 6, and "Update-Database" raised this exception, both with and without "-Force". I just used the SQL Server console to fix this one entry (reduced to 6 characters) and the Update-Database worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on how to debug this or any EF related issues:

[String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated](https://slishnevsky.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-terminated/)

Basically what you have to do is to turn on 'SQL Server Profiler' and turn on 'Exception' and 'RPC:Starting' profilers. When you get your error in profiler, you will be able to see full query that was executed by EF. From there you can copy and paste to MS SQL Server Management Studio run it manually and identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In EF dot net core "code first" one can do this SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = LEFT(MyColumn, 50)
WHERE LEN(MyColumn) > 50
```

In the Migration UP part, one can execute the sql like this:

```
modelBuilder.sql("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = LEFT(MyColumn, 50) WHERE LEN(MyColumn) > 50");
```

Please note that the statement has to be beofre the before the alter of string length.

Answer (score 1):

To me is sounds like you are trying to alter the length/size of a field in a table to be "smaller" then some of the data that already resides in it.

So for example if i have a varchar(28) type field field in my table-- with data that already inside that is 28 characters long... and then I try to execute an alter table to reduce the size to varchar(25) it will say: String or binary data would be truncated

It coul also arise IF you are trying to stuff a String that is lets say 30 cahraters long into a field that only supports 28 characters...

So it can happen if you are trying to insert data into a field and the data is to big to fit essientially

Comment: yes i am trying to alter the length from NVARCHAR(MAX) to nvarchar(60),NVARCHAR(MAX) to nvarchar(30),NVARCHAR(MAX) to nvarchar(5).when i passed the command in package manager console,add-migration DataAnnotations and update-database,this error arises,tell me the solution kindly

Comment: execute this SQL to find the max length of data in column: SELECT  name, LENGTH(name) AS mlen
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        mlen DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: use the max length value when altering your table... otherwise you need to write a special DML SQL UPDATE query to truncate the data explicitly

Comment: @user1500191 Pretty sure `LIMIT 1` isn't available in SQL Server, it's a MySQL thing right?

Comment: sql-server: select max(len(Desc)) from table_name

Answer (score 0):

It is a property length issue.You are trying to insert property's value which length is less than your declared property's length.